# volume generated by parabola and line about $y$ axis

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Using cylindrical method to find volume of regin enclosed by $y=5-x^2$ and $y=1$ and right of $y$ axis revolving around $y$ axis,is

What i try ::

[image]

Here Volume $$V=2\pi\int^{2}_{0}\bigg(2-x^2-1\bigg)dx$$

$$V=2\pi\int^{2}_{0}\bigg(1-x^2\bigg)dx=2\pi\bigg(x-\frac{x^3}{3}\bigg)\bigg|^{2}_{0}=-\frac{2}{3}$$

But volume is not negative.

Please help me where i am wrong. Thanks

Comment: A few things: Did you mean $5-x^2-1$? Also, what formula are you using? It should be $\int_a^b 2\pi x f(x)dx.$

Comment: Thanks Nick D .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is well know formula for volume of revolving over axis $Ox$ plane figure created by $a \leqslant x  \leqslant b$ and $0 \leqslant y  \leqslant f(x)$:
$$V=\pi \int\limits_{a}^{b}f^2(x)\,dx$$
In our case as you have revolving around $y$ axis, then same volume  is giving by $1 \leqslant x  \leqslant 5$ and $0 \leqslant y  \leqslant \sqrt{5-x}$ revolving around $x$ axis.

So we have
$$V=\pi \int\limits_{1}^{5}(5-x)\,dx = 8\pi$$